# Xcode unit test error "Could not get GOOGLE_APP_ID in Google Services file from build environment"

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, crashlytics

I've added a unit test target to an Xcode project but am getting this error when attempting to run the tests

> Could not get GOOGLE_APP_ID in Google Services file from build
> environment

The app being tested uses Firebase and I've tried adding the GoogleService-Info.plist to the test project in addition to the app but the error remains.

I have added a target section for the unit tests within the podfile spec and added  inherit! :complete  and also tried explicitly adding firebase to the test pod section, nothing makes this error go away.

Comment: Did you ever find a fix to this? Having the same error all of sudden when it's been fine for months